# Retrieving snapshots from firestore sub-collection to dart/flutter object

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

New here.  I've googled everything and can't figure this out.
The first two functions below work flawlessly the third always return null immediately without calling my ListFromSnapShot function, which just turns the map into a list. I am assuming

I'm not calling the Firestore correctly but I have no idea how to do this properly.

```
final CollectionReference customerCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('customers');
final CollectionReference jobCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('jobs');  

// get user doc stream
Stream<UserData> get userData {
 return customerCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
  .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
}   
      //Returns only snapshots with matching customer name to StreamProvider object
Stream<List<Job>> get jobQuery {
 return jobCollection.where('customerName', isEqualTo: currentCustomer.companyName)
  .snapshots()
  .map(_jobListFromSnapshot);
}   
//The following always returns Null 
Stream<List<JobSectionModel>> get jobQuerySections {

return jobCollection.document('Family Dollar').collection('sections')
  .snapshots()
  .map(_jobSectionListFromSnapshot);
```

This is my database structure
Base Collection
[image: Base Collection]

Subcollection
[image: Subcollection]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Someone edited this comment to include the images in the post, which I appreciate, but unfortunately added the same image twice.  The second image is of the subcollection.  Stackoverflow lets me edit the text but not the embedded image if someone could change this that would be cool.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The code above does work, the problem, after several frustrating days, ended up being random spaces in the firestore path.  I'm posting this as an answer because after googling this there were many others with a similar problem and I don't want them to go through the same frustration.  Firestore will not show this until you literally click on the path name and it will not crash your program, it just returns nothing.

Do yourself a favor and use the .trim() function when adding data and if you do it manually on firestore make sure there's no trailing spaces.

Also I rebuilt the code as follows which also works (without spaces of course)

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getjobQuerySections(BuildContext context) async*{

  yield* jobCollection.document('T-MOBILE').collection('whyspaces').snapshots();
```

Hope this helps someone.  Good Luck